# Compilation Error with Boost.Geometry and NVCC (CUDA 12.4): '__T0' does not name a type

Tags: boost, compiler-errors, cuda, nvcc, boost-geometry

I'm encountering a compilation error when trying to compile a project using Boost.Geometry with NVCC, part of CUDA 12.4. The project compiles fine with GCC alone, but when NVCC is involved, it throws errors related to type naming in Boost.Geometry's *sectionalize.hpp*.

This issue is not present when compiling with CUDA versions 12.3 and below

#### Environment:

- **Compiler**: GCC 9.5.0, NVCC from CUDA 12.4
- **Boost Version**: 1.84.0
- **Build System**: Makefile

#### Error Logs:

```
[ 33%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/testGeometry.dir/main.cu.o
/home/marekz/boost-1.84.0/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/sections/sectionalize.hpp: In function ‘void boost::geometry::detail::sectionalize::enlarge_sections(Sections&, const Strategy&)’:
/home/marekz/boost-1.84.0/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/sections/sectionalize.hpp:739:12: error: ‘__T0’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__y0’?
  739 |         using gt = decltype(section.bounding_box);
      |            ^~~~
      |            __y0
/home/marekz/boost-1.84.0/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/sections/sectionalize.hpp:740:38: error: ‘__T0’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘__y0’?
  740 |         using ct = typename geometry::coordinate_type<gt>::type;
      |                                      ^~~~
      |                                      __y0
/home/marekz/boost-1.84.0/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/sections/sectionalize.hpp:740:42: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  740 |         using ct = typename geometry::coordinate_type<gt>::type;
      |                                          ^
/home/marekz/boost-1.84.0/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/sections/sectionalize.hpp:741:14: error: ‘ct’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘cs’?
  741 |         static ct const eps = math::scaled_epsilon<ct>(1000);
      |              ^~
      |              cs
/home/marekz/boost-1.84.0/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/sections/sectionalize.hpp:742:43: error: ‘eps’ was not declared in this scope
  742 |         expand_by_epsilon(section.bounding_box, eps);
      |                                           ^~~
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/testGeometry.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/testGeometry.dir/main.cu.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/testGeometry.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/testGeometry.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:124: testGeometry] Error 2
```

To produce the problem I created a test program:
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(testGeometry CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc-9")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++-9")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++-9")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

enable_language(CUDA)

include(FindCUDAToolkit)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} --std c++17")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} --maxrregcount 32")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} --expt-relaxed-constexpr")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH};/home/marekz/boost-1.84.0/lib/cmake")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cu)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        CUDA::cudart
        Boost::headers
        PRIVATE
        CUDA::curand
        CUDA::cusolver
)
```

main.cu

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Define the point type
    using point_t = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;

    // Define the polygon type
    using polygon_t = boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_t>;

    // Create a point
    point_t point(5.0, 5.0);

    // Create a polygon
    polygon_t poly;
    boost::geometry::append(poly.outer(), point_t(0.0, 0.0));
    boost::geometry::append(poly.outer(), point_t(0.0, 10.0));
    boost::geometry::append(poly.outer(), point_t(10.0, 10.0));
    boost::geometry::append(poly.outer(), point_t(10.0, 0.0));
    boost::geometry::append(poly.outer(), point_t(0.0, 0.0));

    // Calculate the distance
    double dist = boost::geometry::distance(point, poly);

    std::cout << "Distance between the point and the polygon is: " << dist << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don’t use nvcc to compile Boost code. It is known to fail on extremely complex template and template metaprogramming code. Quarantine the boost code into a separate translation unit and use g++ for that, and restrict nvcc to CUDA code

Comment: @talonmies I have not run into this myself before, but that's sound advice nonetheless

Comment: @sehe: It’s not just boost. QT famously also has this problem. The advice has been the same since CUDA switched to a C++ host compiler front end in about 2009. There is no getting around the fact that a front end parser looking for `<<<>>>` is going to have a lot of problems parsing super complicated C++ template libraries